# Susy not removing last padding of item

Tags: css, sass, susy, susy-sass

I want to create a simple 4 row grit with susy, but recently i'm not able to get this working. I created the problem in Sassmeister:
[Link to problem in Sassmeister](http://sassmeister.com/gist/589531247badb99a93ae)

Is there something i miss here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add …

```
  &:last-child {
    @include last();
  }
```

… below `article`. This will result in the last (4th) article *not* having a `margin-right` and hence it will fit in the row.